# integrating solr autosuggest functionality error

Tags: solr, autocomplete, autosuggest, solr4

I am trying to integrate auto suggest functionality of solr in my project. I use [this](http://www.cominvent.com/2012/01/25/super-flexible-autocomplete-with-solr/) as my starting point. I changed my searched fields accordingly.

my schema.xml

```
<field name="name" type="text_suggest" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="manu" type="text_suggest" indexed="true" stored="true"/>  
<field name="popularity" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" />

<!-- A variant of textsuggest which only matches from the very left edge -->
<copyField source="name" dest="textnge"/>
<field name="textnge" type="autocomplete_edge" indexed="true" stored="false" />

<!-- A variant of name which matches from the left edge of all terms (implicit truncation) -->
<copyField source="name" dest="textng"/>
<field name="textng" type="autocomplete_ngram" indexed="true" stored="false" omitNorms="true" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" />
```

My request handler in solrconfig.xml

```
<requestHandler class="solr.SearchHandler" name="/ac" default="true" >
    <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="defType">edismax</str>
    <str name="rows">10</str>
    <str name="fl">*,score</str>
    <str name="qf">name^50 manu^20.0 textng^50.0</str>
    <str name="pf">textnge^50.0</str>
    <str name="bf">product(log(sum(popularity,1)),100)^20</str>
    <str name="debugQuery">false</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

The problem is that my "/ac" handler is acting more like "/select" handler. When I type "moni" I am getting nothing. But when I type "monitor", its returning me the documents containing monitor in them.

I have been trying this for whole day and nothing seems to work. Any help will be deeply appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Well when you look for "moni" in your query, you are actually specifically saying that you're looking for the "moni" keyword. Try looking for multiterms keywrods by adding "*", such as `q=moni*`.

You can also look in other fieldType analyser like `autocomplete_edge (q=textnge:mori)` or `autocomplete_ngram (q=textng:mori)` for more data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify search component in solarconfig.xml like below

```
<searchComponent class="solr.SpellCheckComponent" name="ac">
        <lst name="spellchecker">
            <str name="name">suggest</str>
            <str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>
            <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.tst.TSTLookupFactory</str>
            <str name="field">yourfieldname</str>  <!-- the indexed field to derive suggestions from -->
            <float name="threshold">0.005</float>
            <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
        </lst>
    </searchComponent>
```